# Calling a function when DOM is updated in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to call a function after DOM loading and I'm using the below code :

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log("DOM is loaded")
});
```

Now I want to have an event that calls a function or print a string in the console when DOM is updating.
How can I do this?

Comment: DOM Mutation Observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MutationObserver is what you are looking for, here is the MDN docs link for the same,

[Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)